# Python question: parameter estimation of ODE systems such that coefficients are functions

Tags: python, parameters, odeint, estimation

[image]

My model is ODE systems that coefficients are functions having parameters.

My goal is parameter estimation in coefficients.

```
dC1dt = c_11(t)*C1 + c_12(t)*C2

dC2dt = c_22(t)*C2 + c_22(t)*C2
```

I know how to solve it with R but I have to solve it with Python.

First of all, I tried to use odeint in fixed conditions.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# fixed values
V_room = 40 #room volume[m^3]
v = 0.01 #velocity of material [m/s]
h = 2.5 # height of room [m/s]
Q = 1 # average flux [m^3/min]
V_0 =1 # initial value of nf [m^3]
Q_0 = 0.1 #initial value of Q_ff

#initial values 
C_0 = [0.0002, 2e-05]

#parameter 
k= 0.06       
beta = 0.001
alpha = 0.005

# measured time
ts = np.linspace(0,60,60)
# fixed functions

def V_nf(t):
    return V_0 + (V_room - V_0)*(1-np.exp(-alpha*t))

def V_ff(t):
    return V_room - V_nf(t)

def dVnf(t):
    return alpha*(V_nf(t)-V_0)

def dVff(t):
    return -dVnf(t)

def S_nf(t):
    return V_nf(t)**(2/3)

def Q_ff(t):
    return Q_0*np.exp(-beta*t)
```

=====

```
coefficients = {'coef_11' : coef11, 'coef_12' : coef12, 'coef_21' : coef21, 'coef_22' : coef22}

def coef11(t):
    return (-k*S_nf(t)-dVnf(t))/V_nf(t) - Q/V_room - v/h

def coef12(t):
    return (k*S_nf(t)+Q_ff(t))/V_nf(t) - Q*V_ff(t)/(V_room * V_nf(t))

def coef21(t):
    return k*S_nf(t)/V_ff(t)

def coef22(t):
    return (-dVff(t)-Q_ff(t)-k*S_nf(t))/V_ff(t) - v/h

def dCdt(C,t):
    
    C_nf = C[0]
    C_ff = C[1]
    c_11 = coefficients['coef_11'](t)
    c_12 = coefficients['coef_12'](t)
    c_21 = coefficients['coef_21'](t)
    c_22 = coefficients['coef_22'](t)
    
    dCnf = c_11* C_nf + c_12 * C_ff
    dCff = c_21* C_nf + c_22 * C_ff
    
    return [dCnf, dCff]

C = odeint(dCdt, C_0, ts, args= (coefficients,))
```

However, I got

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-7cece3e6a166> in <module>
     13     return [dCnf, dCff]
     14 
---> 15 C = odeint(dCdt, C_0, ts, args= (coefficients,))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    242                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
--> 244                              int(bool(tfirst)))
    245     if output[-1] < 0:
    246         warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

TypeError: dCdt() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I don't know if this method is correct and why this problem happens.

As I said, my goal is estimation of parameters(k,alpha,beta).

Hence if you know how to that, use data.

Data:

```
C1 = array([2.00000e-04, 3.52006e+00, 1.01378e+00, 8.47760e-01, 6.19000e-01,
   6.09940e-01, 4.35010e-01, 3.49150e-01, 3.87830e-01, 3.24830e-01,
   1.97040e-01, 1.84630e-01, 1.72520e-01, 1.35980e-01, 1.38430e-01,
   1.21520e-01, 1.46680e-01, 9.08900e-02, 1.09650e-01, 8.71000e-02,
   9.24400e-02, 1.11200e-01, 7.96600e-02, 9.26300e-02, 8.08700e-02,
   8.04000e-02, 7.69200e-02, 9.06400e-02, 7.30600e-02, 7.22200e-02,
   6.57900e-02, 7.87200e-02, 7.67700e-02, 7.28100e-02, 6.65600e-02,
   6.87300e-02, 7.65600e-02, 6.87200e-02, 7.52700e-02, 8.66000e-02,
   6.90700e-02, 6.51900e-02, 5.39200e-02, 6.46600e-02, 5.96400e-02,
   6.90100e-02, 6.23700e-02, 1.00230e-01, 9.05900e-02, 4.96300e-02,
   6.75400e-02, 5.50200e-02, 4.75700e-02, 5.82800e-02, 5.34400e-02,
   5.30200e-02, 4.10700e-02, 4.10800e-02, 4.91300e-02, 4.16300e-02])

C2 = array([5.000e-05, 2.000e-05, 1.000e-04, 1.250e-03, 1.500e-03, 2.630e-03,
   2.600e-04, 5.540e-03, 2.160e-03, 9.420e-03, 8.030e-03, 1.369e-02,
   9.620e-03, 1.527e-02, 1.209e-02, 9.600e-03, 1.081e-02, 1.414e-02,
   1.522e-02, 1.244e-02, 2.223e-02, 2.312e-02, 2.683e-02, 2.398e-02,
   2.658e-02, 2.841e-02, 2.123e-02, 3.052e-02, 3.349e-02, 4.027e-02,
   3.110e-02, 3.134e-02, 3.185e-02, 2.964e-02, 4.078e-02, 2.530e-02,
   4.443e-02, 2.856e-02, 2.459e-02, 2.568e-02, 2.104e-02, 2.477e-02,
   2.297e-02, 2.512e-02, 2.133e-02, 2.002e-02, 1.427e-02, 3.033e-02,
   1.946e-02, 2.173e-02, 1.800e-02, 1.346e-02, 2.039e-02, 2.132e-02,
   1.416e-02, 1.376e-02, 1.079e-02, 6.640e-03, 1.324e-02, 1.056e-02])
```

Comment: Did you mean `linspace(0,60,61)` instead of `linspace(0,60,60)`? With (0,60,61) you get a time step of exactly 1.0, but with (0,60,60) you get time step of 1.0169. Also, are you sure your C1 data is good, or is there a typo? It seems to me that the first data point doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the TypeError because you forgot an argument in the definition of the `dCdt` function. It should be `def dCdt(C,t,coefficients):`.

As for the parameter optimization, there are many different methods and approaches for that. What method did you use in R? One of the easiest ways of finding good parameters in python is by minimizing the sum of squared errors with `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

```
def SumSquaredErr(x):
    k,alpha,beta = x
    
    # Insert all your function definitions here #
    
    C = odeint(dCdt, C_0, ts, args= (coefficients,))

    return ((C[1:,0] - C1)**2).sum() + ((C[1:,1] - C2)**2).sum()

x0 = [k,alpha,beta] # your best guess for the parameter values
bounds = [(None,None),(0,None),(None,None)] # alpha>0 so V_nf!=0
res = minimize(SumSquaredErr, x0, bounds=bounds)
print('best [k,alpha,beta]: ', res.x)
```

I am assuming here that `ts = np.linspace(0,60,61)` and that C1 and C2 are the data for times `ts[1:]`, i.e. 1,2,3,...,59,60.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used ,in R, library(deSolve) # library for solving differential equations
library(minpack.lm) # library for least squares fit using levenberg-marquardt algorithm

Comment: @Galois . In that case you can use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` with `method='lm'`, which is "Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in MINPACK", so literally the same algorithm you used in R.